# PHP GET and POST - not working

Tags: php, csv

I am a beginner with php and have the following code for getting values from a form and inserting it into a csv file as an array

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['submitted'])){
   $csvData = [$_GET["contract"],$_GET["article"],$_GET["specs"]];
   $fp = fopen("order.csv","a"); 
   if($fp)    {  
       fputcsv($fp,$csvData); // Write information to the file
       fclose($fp); // Close the file
   }
}
```

HTML :

```
 <form  action="add.php" method="GET" >
            <label class="wsite-form-label" >Contract No <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
            <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
                <input    name="contract" id='contract'>
            </div>

            <label class="wsite-form-label" >Article <span class="form-required">*</span></label>
            <div class="wsite-form-input-container">
                <input  name="article">
            </div>

            <label class="wsite-form-label"> SPECS<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
                <input name="specs">
                <button type='submit' name="submitted" value="true" >Submit </button>
 </form>
```

Have tried both get and post but still not able to get inserted value to my php. please help.

Comment: You have missed the values in input fields, Try to add the values to all three input fields. Hope this works for you.

Comment: @SarvagnaMehta: `value` attribute is not necessary if you are taking input from user. check [this](http://jsbin.com/suqeyeqepi/1/)

Comment: you may not have the permission to write to a file, just var_dump($csvData), then work from there

Comment: i have tried with a sample array by assigning string values directly and it is apppending in the file , just not able to get it from the form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code

```
  <?php
         if(isset($_GET['submitted']))
         {
              $csvData = array($_GET["contract"],$_GET["article"],$_GET["specs"]);
              $fp = fopen("order.csv","a"); 
              if($fp) 
                   fputcsv($fp,$csvData);
              file fclose($fp); // Close the file
         } 
    ?>

    <html>
         <head>
            <title>dfsdfdsdfsdfs</title>
         </head>
         <body>
                 <form  action="test.php" method="GET" >
                           /* Your Form */
                 </form>
         </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: thanks , but still not working , tried var_dump in the php but says csvData is undefined , so does that mean i am not getting values from GET to my variables ?

Comment: Can you post your code again. Because i tried my code its worked very well. That's why i posted to you

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

```
if(!empty($_GET["contract"]) && !empty($_GET["article"]) && !empty($_GET["specs"])){
   $csvData = array($_GET["contract"],$_GET["article"],$_GET["specs"]);
   $fp = fopen("order.csv","a"); 
   if($fp)    {  
       fputcsv($fp,$csvData); // Write information to the file
       fclose($fp); // Close the file
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks , but still not working , tried var_dump in the php but says csvData is undefined , so does that mean i am not getting values from GET to my variables ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no errors in your code. You can check this by using

```
var_dump($csvData);
```

if it works then check the file pointer $fp
You can find more details about fopen() [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: have tried this , but says csvData is undefined , so does that mean i am not getting values from GET to my variables ?